# Button background condition

Tags: android, background, conditional-statements

how can I create a condition if a button has set a backround and set another?

for example I would like to create a button with 2 conditions click

code:

```
suono.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
               public void onClick(View v){

                   if(//has suonoff as background  ){
                       Button suonoff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsoundoff);
                       suonoff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.suonon);

                     }


                   Button suonoff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsoundoff);
                   suonoff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.suonoff);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maintain one flag for click or not, chane the state of the flag.

```
boolean flag=true;
suonoff.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(flag){
                        suonoff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.suonon);
                        flag=false;
                    }else{
                        suonoff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.suonoff);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
Button suonoff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsoundoff);
if(suonoff.getBackground() == null){

    suonoff.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.suonon));
}
```

Or

```
Button suonoff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsoundoff);
if(suonoff.getBackground() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.suonon)){

    suonoff.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.suonoff));
}
```

Comment: thanks but the background is not null, and the other code give me this problem : Incompatible operand types Drawable and int